# How Can I Make Inherited Tests Run First for JUNIT4

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, android-espresso

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
open class BaseTest {

@Test
fun a_firstTest() {
//code
}
}

class myTest : BaseTest() {

@Test
fun b_secondTest() {
//code
}
}
```

So i setup my espresso tests using the page object model and the problem I'm running into is I need the a_firstTest to run before all but it always runs last. I suspect its because I extend off the baseTest class and it just ignores the @FixMethodOrder I tried adding that to the myTest class as well and no luck any insight would be appreciated!